# Maven Generated Project looks different when importing to Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

I was trying to generate a Simple Spring-MVC project using this 
[this](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-web-application-project-with-maven/) tutorial

However. upon importing the project in eclipse. there  were several errors(well for me atleast)

First is this.

The packages are colored white. what I was expecting is the packages should be brown, like the normal projects in Eclipse.

[image]

Next. When Implemented the interface Named IndexController. it told me this error

> "The Resource is not on the build path of a Java Project

what have I done wrong?

Comment: Did you import your project "as a Maven project"

Comment: Are you putting your java files under src/main/resource?

Comment: No I didn't I just imported it as a Java Project. and yes. I've put the java files under the src/main/resource

Comment: Hi - acdcjunior is correct: the directory structure you're trying to import into Eclipse isn't correct.  Q: Did you follow this part in the tutorial: `mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your `.java` files are in the `resources` folder. They should be at a `/java/` one.**

The workaround is shown below, but first, understand what's going on:

In the Maven default folder structure, Java source files (`.java`) should be in the 
`/src/*/java` folders, such as `/src/main/java` and `/src/test/java`.

The `/src/*/resources` folders are reserved for resources to be used by the program, like configuration/properties files, images and so on:

```
src
|--main
|  |--java
|  |  |--com
|  |  |  |--mypackage
|  |  |     |--MyClassA.java
|  |  |     |--submypackage
|  |  |        |--SomeOtherClass.java
|  |  |--net
|  |     |--netpackage
|  |        |--MyNetClassA.java
|  |--resources
|     |--myAppConfig.xml
|--test
   |--java
   |  |--com
   |     |--anotherpackage
   |        |--AnotherClassTest.java
   |--resources
```

### How to fix it:

Create a `/java/` source folder and place your `.java` files there:

- Right-click on ***Java Resources***
- Select ***New***
- Select ***Source Folder***
- Select your project and give the folder the name `src/main/java`:

[image: creating source folder]

The `src/main/java` should be created. **Move the packages (the `com.todolist.*` items) with the `.java` files there.**

If you can, just to make sure Maven/Eclipse catches up to the new structure: right-click your project and click `Maven` -> `Update Project...`:

[image: maven update project]

Comment: when I generated the project. there's no src/main/java. I don't know why.

Comment: are there any way I can make maven make that its structure?

Comment: Yeah, I've seen it before (not create the `/java/` folder). I added how to work around it to the answer. Check it out.

Comment: Run? as in Run as? I don't see any run on my project

Comment: Oh, I meant click. Added some images to help.